# How to remotely run a (shebang prefixed) node script using ssh?

Tags: node.js, openssh, shebang

I want to remotely run a node.js script containing a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509816/what-exactly-does-usr-bin-env-node-do-at-the-beginning-of-node-files) through `ssh`, similarly as when running it locally.

`myscript` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var param  = process.argv[2] || 'help';
//... other js code
```

When running locally on each host – e.g. `myscript arg1` – it runs successfully. When running remotely on a "sister" node in a cluster (containing the same file and directory structure, including `node`and `myscript`):

```
ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication no" bob@123.1.2.3 /path/to/myscript arg1
```

I get `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory` error.

**Am I missing a `ssh` param / option?**

---

Mode details: If I run

```
ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication no" bob@123.1.2.3 echo "hello"
```

It also works fine. Forgive me it this is obvious to you, I'm not an advanced Linux user, the [ssh manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5) seemed a little bit overwhelming and tried a couple answers found here with no success:

1. [What exactly does "/usr/bin/env node" do at the beginning of node files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509816/what-exactly-does-usr-bin-env-node-do-at-the-beginning-of-node-files)
2. [Run scripts remotely via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937634/run-scripts-remotely-via-ssh)
3. [how to run a script file remotely using ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041597/how-to-run-a-script-file-remotely-using-ssh)

Comment: Are you positive that `node` is installed the same on all nodes in the cluster?

Comment: I get that message when node is not installed or the path to node is wrong

Comment: Please check if this will run `ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication no" bob@123.1.2.3 bash -c "/path/to/myscript arg1"`

Comment: Question edited. Yes, `node` and `myscript` are installed in the same location; and no, bash -c "..." didn't get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

If the `node` executable isn't already in your `PATH` environment variable at login, you could provide the full path to it in the shebang line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /full/path/to/node
```

As others have commented, you would have to update your script if the path to `node` ever changes. This is not ideal. Alternatively, you could force `ssh` to create a pseudo-terminal session by specifying the `-t` flag and run your script in an interactive bash shell:

```
ssh -t -o "PasswordAuthentication no" bob@123.1.2.3 'bash -ic "/path/to/myscript arg1"'
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian - I think this may be a working solution, but note that it's not an elegant solution - especially if you choose to use different versions of node etc. Hardcoding the full path to node could potentially affect the work of version managers like `nvm`...

Comment: Both local and remote hosts' `PATH` properly point to `node` and `myscript` locations. However, your suggestion worked after also adding quotes to `"/path/to/myscript arg1"`. Is there a way, then, to make sure path is loaded *by `ssh`*, instead of hardcoding the  `/full/path/to/node` onto `myscript`? This could cause a regression in case node's location is changed in the future...

Comment: @Ricardo, perhaps there is a solution... can you do the following: `ssh <opts> -t 'bash -ic '"'"'echo $PATH'"'"''`? I suppose the output will be somewhat different to `ssh <opts> -t 'echo $PATH'`... it's probably a matter where you actually set the path.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55364848/1159167) inspired me to find a solution that doesn't hardcode the full path to `node` on the script. Basically, I make sure the remote `PATH` is available before running the command:

```
ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication no" bob@123.1.2.3 "export PATH=$PATH;/path/to/myscript arg1"
```

But this **only worked for me** because both local and remote servers have the same `PATH` value, since the local `PATH` is being set onto the remote session.

---

Here there may be some ways to explore other solutions if your case is not like mine:

1. [How do I set $PATH such that `ssh user@host command` works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works)
2. [How to set PATH when running a ssh command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/how-to-set-path-when-running-a-ssh-command)

Comment: It also worked w/o adding quotes: `ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication no" bob@123.1.2.3 export PATH=$PATH;/path/to/myscript arg1`